# Count if "YES" in 1 field or another in Tablean

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to create a calculated field in tableau that will count if one field OR another contains 'yes' - and then add the YES's together as a value.

I have tried CASE WHEN, IF, COUNTIF but I am having trouble as I have to have the OR in the calculated field.

Here is my last attempt that also failed:

COUNTIF([M-CROSSC (Cross Country)]) = 'YES' OR ([W-CROSSC (Cross Country)])= 'YES' THEN '1' END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Put the if statement inside the count().

COUNT(IF [M-CROSSC (Cross Country)] = 'YES' OR ([W-CROSSC (Cross Country)]= 'YES' THEN '1' END)

edited to remove extra ')' after each dimension.

Comment: I get the error message "Expected 'THEN to match 'IF' at character 8"....

Comment: check the brackets

Comment: Bernardo’ s solution is correct. FYI, Another variant is SUM(INT([M-CROSSC (Cross Country)] = ‘YES’ OR [W-CROSSCUT (Cross Country)] = ‘YES’)) saving 10 whole characters worth of typing. It works because the function INT() converts TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.